# "Loadmore" button is not working in buddypress

Tags: ajax, buddypress, buttons

"Load-more" button in the activity stream page in buddypress is not working for me. If clicked means , it disappearing suddenly but no more posts are loaded.

```
<?php if ( bp_get_activity_count() == bp_get_activity_per_page() ) : ?>
    <li class="load-more clear">
        <a href="#more"><?php _e( 'Load More', 'buddypress' ) ?></a> &nbsp; <span class="ajax-loader"></span>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to load activities like Facebook or by means of load more button.
So I tried the following code snippet got from [buddypress forum](http://buddypress.org/community/groups/creating-extending/forum/topic/auto-load-more-activity-stream-items-when-scroll-reaches-the-bottom-of-the-page/)

```
    // Change:
```

```
<li class="load-more">
    <a href="#more"><?php _e( 'Load More', 'buddypress' ); ?></a>
</li>
```

// For this:

```
<?php if ( ! bp_activity_has_more_items() ) : ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jq('.pixelMonitor').remove();
        jq(document).unbind('scroll');
    </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

// 2) Add this at the bottom of that file:

```
<div class="pixelMonitor"  style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: fixed; bottom: 0;">
<div id="loadingActivityMessage" style="background-color: white; border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px; bottom: 4px; display: none; float: right; height: 16px; padding: 4px 2px 4px 39px; position: fixed; width: 100px;">Loading...</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/* Auto load more updates at the end of the page when reaching the bottom of the page */

    jq(document).ready( function() {

    iterationAllowed = true;

    function loadActivityOnScroll(){

        jq("#loadingActivityMessage").show();

        if ( null == jq.cookie('bp-activity-oldestpage') )
            jq.cookie('bp-activity-oldestpage', 1, {path: '/'} );

        var oldest_page = ( jq.cookie('bp-activity-oldestpage') * 1 ) + 1;

        jq.post( ajaxurl, {
            action: 'activity_get_older_updates',
            'cookie': encodeURIComponent(document.cookie),
            'page': oldest_page
        },
        function(response){
            jq("#loadingActivityMessage").hide();
            jq.cookie( 'bp-activity-oldestpage', oldest_page, {path: '/'} );
            jq("#content ul.activity-list").append(response.contents);

        }, 'json' );

        return false;

    };

    jq(document).scroll(function(){       

        if ( Math.round(jq('.pixelMonitor').last().offset().top) > ( jq(document).height() -500 ) && iterationAllowed === true ) {
            loadActivityOnScroll();
            iterationAllowed = false;
            setTimeout('iterationAllowed = true', 3000);
        };

    });

}); /* Auto load more activity block ending here */

</script>
```

Does any one got this and get solved?
Please ,

Thanks in advance.

```
<li class="load-more">
    <a href="#more"><?php _e( 'Load More', 'buddypress' ); ?></a>
</li>
```

I have added back the following code with all 
and now it s working when I'm clicking the Load more button but the "Loadmore..." is not showing!

Comment: @toscho Thank You, for you code formatting .. I too tried it.

Comment: Our [editing help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help) is not easy to find … but worth a read. :) I have made a simple [cheat sheet](http://labs.toscho.de/sidebar/markdown.html) that fits into a browser sidebar.

Comment: I have added back the following code with all
<li class="load-more">
    <a href="#more"><?php _e( 'Load More', 'buddypress' ); ?></a>
</li>
and now it s working when I'm clicking the Load more button but the "Loadmore..." is not showing!

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be inside a div with id "content" in order to work (check the buddypress global.js file to see why!)